# INSERT NULL if a field is left blank (decimal) MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert, null

I have a if `NULL` echo "Message" else `$value`.

There is some JavaScript hiding the input field, so they check it and enter the value.

If they don't check it to enter the field, the db enters 0.00 and doesn't specify `NULL` so my PHP if statement works.

How do I either set the variable as `NULL` if its blank, or set `NULL` in the `INSERT` statement?

```
`myTableField` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're after, but you can run the below if statement to check what value was entered, and set to null accordingly:

```
if(!is_numeric($fieldvalue) || $fieldvalue==0){
  // if the entered value isnt a number (i.e. isnt entered, or invalid) or if the value is zero, sounded like it was your default
  $fieldvalue=NULL;
  // could also use unset($fieldvalue);
}
```

If the variable $fieldvalue is set to null (or un-set), it will be inserted as a NULL in your DB according to your field definitions. Make sure your insert statement references the value without ' or " encapsulating figures however (not needed as its a decimal field).

Comment: $variable=$_POST[myvariable]; I've added the above code after my $_POST, but it's still adding 0.00..

Comment: @SMacFadyen, have you ever heard of SQL-injection?